# How to make view on top of another view in CoordinatorLayout?

Tags: android

this is my view. I want all all views in `mainContainer` be on top of the screen. And if views from `secondContainer` are at the same position they need to be covered by views from `mainContainer`.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/mainContainer"
        layout="@layout/view_home_content"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom"/>

    <include
        android:id="@+id/secondContainer"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior"/>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Now everything from `secondContainer` appears on top of views from `mainContainer`

Answer (score 0):

Oh the solution was easy. I just changed the order of views

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<include
    android:id="@+id/secondContainer"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior"/>

<include
    android:id="@+id/mainContainer"
    layout="@layout/view_home_content"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom"/>


</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: You can also put the elevation in you "view_home_content" e.g android:elevation="1dp" to achive the same thing without changing the order.